# Real-time chat with +1M users distributed backend solution on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, instant-messaging, realtime

I Need to deploy a backend solution for a mass messaging iPhone app. Based on coverage previous apps we have deployed it is safe to assume we will get over 1 million signups in the first week and that could grow rapidly.

I am interested in deploying a load balanced cluster solution on AWS that can grow and shrink on demand, that is reliable as well as time and cost effective.

I've already done a lot of research but dont want to steer this feed towards any specific solution, and explore as many as possible.

At the moment an XMPP solution like OpenFire with a clustering sounds like a good start. But I have never tried any of these systems or know how they would behave with +1M users.

I am very open to explore many solutions with the aim of getting started on the right track.

Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into [ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/), which provides several clustering features that should make it rather easy to scale the way you want.  It's been used for deployments much larger than 1MM users (see: Facebook Chat).

Comment: Thanks, after doing a lot of research this seems to be the best option based on: How well it clusters, and how efficient it is with resources.